# Right hook to redirect frontend visitors while respecting rest api plugins to run first?

Tags: redirect, rest-api

I don't need a frontend on the WP site. All visitors will be redirected to an external url where my frontend app lives.

I now have the following code in the root of my theme functions.php:

```
if ( ! is_admin() ) {
  wp_redirect( 'http://www.example.com', 200 );
  exit;
}
```

Unfortunately this runs before the plugins needed to set up the rest api have run.

Where should I place this code to get it right?

---

#### Warning!

See answers(s) below.

Found a solution myself:

```
add_action( 'wp_loaded', function () {
  // check if there is a 'wp-json' URI part
  if (! strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'wp-json')) {
    // No rest api request. Now check if we are on frontend
    if ( ! is_admin() ) {
      // We are on frontend: redirect now
      wp_redirect( 'http://www.example.com', 200 );
      exit();
    }
  }
});
```

The above code works fine (tested) if put in a plugin file.

The above code does not work (tested) when put in the root of theme `functions.php` file.

Comment: The code in your functions.php should not be running first. Plugins always run before themes (unless you or a plugin has hacked WP core).... Is the plugin doing something that takes a few seconds? What exactly does it need to do when it 'runs'? Is it waiting for a response from another domain?

Comment: Which hook are you currently using?

Comment: Maybe [this question and it's answers](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/160279) can help?

Comment: @birgure: Doesn't help but thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The correct solution is to add the redirect to `index.php` in your theme - this will ensure only frontend, non-api based requests are handled.

Sniffing `wp-json` in the request is dodgy at best, and will all out break if another plugin overrides the endpoint (which you can do, [it's pluggable](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/rest_url_prefix/)).

```
<?php

wp_redirect( 'http://example.com/', 301 );
exit;
```

...in `wp-content/themes/your-theme/index.php`. And make sure your theme has no other template files, other than a blank `functions.php`, and the theme's `style.css`

Comment: This indeed works as a charm. Could you spend a few words on how this flow works?

Comment: It's pretty simple - WordPress will load `index.php` as the default template for _all_ "normal" frontend requests. However, instead of serving up a theme, we dish out a redirect.